# Separate delimited Excel data into 2 columns

Tags: parsing, excel, vba

I have some email addresses in column A in Excel. There are many rows, however the names are attached in the same cell with each email address, so it looks like this:

```
johnsmith:johnsmith@gmail.com
adamsmith:adam1i2@gmail.com
CoryAdam:Cory1991@gmail.com
```

Is there a way (in Excel) to separate the data so that I can maintain my rows but have the names in one column and the email addresses in another column? Also would I be able to do this automatically, say at the end of each day or so?

Comment: without a separator, tthere is no way to parse it.  What format is the source data in?

Comment: chris has given you an automated solution. You might also consider using Text to Columns, with `:` as the delimiter.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose an email exists in column C3, you can try the following (write the formula in column D3):

`=LEFT(C3,FIND("@",C3)-1)`

You can then apply the same formula to all rows.

Comment: sorry if i was not clear, the data is all in column A and is done in rows example A1,A2,A3 ect. there is a common separator so the data is name:email (A1) name:email (A2), with : being the separator, i wonder is it possible to have excel automatically separate the name into column a and the email into column b?

Comment: If there is a separator (like a colon), you should edit your question to reflect that. With a separator (aka delimiter), this is an easy problem to solve and can be done via formulas or the Text-to-Columns feature in Excel.

Comment: ah^^ thanks for this information, is it possible to have excel automatically run this task in x amount of time or run this on opening the file?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment to @user496607 's answer, your data is actually

```
johnsmith:johnsmith@gmail.com
adamsmith:adam1i2@gmail.com
CoryAdam:Cory1991@gmail.com
```

In column `A`.  Is this correct?

You want to have Excel automatically split this into columns `A` and `B` each time the workbook is opened?

This `Sub` wit\ll do the split

```
Sub SplitNames(sh As Worksheet)
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim dat As Variant
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, s As String

    Set rng = sh.Range(sh.Cells(1, 1), sh.Cells(sh.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))

    'rng.Select
    dat = rng.Formula
    If IsArray(dat) Then
        ReDim Preserve dat(1 To UBound(dat, 1), 1 To 2)
        For i = LBound(dat, 1) To UBound(dat, 1)
            s = dat(i, 1)
            j = InStr(dat(i, 1), ":")
            If Left(s, 1) <> "=" And j > 0 Then
                dat(i, 2) = Mid(s, j + 1)
                dat(i, 1) = Left(s, j - 1)
            End If
        Next
        rng.Resize(, 2).Formula = dat
    End If
End Sub
```

This may be called by another `Sub` on what ever trigger you want.  For example this will call it on `Workbook` open (put this in `ThisWorkbook` module)

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    For Each sh In Me.Worksheets
        SplitNames sh
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an automated solution using Text to columns. It will work as long as your data always begins in cell A1, as you said it does:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)).Select
                Selection.textToColumns Destination:=Range("A1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
                TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=False, _
                Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=False, Other:=True, OtherChar _
                :=":"
End Sub
```

Put it in the `ThisWorkbook` module and it will run every time you open the workbook.